# How to obtain the equations of motion and trajectory of a particle from the effective potential?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, coordinate-systems, potential-energy

In a certain problem regarding motion of a particle in a gravitational field with axial symmetry, I have an expression of an effective potential $\Phi_{eff}(r,\theta)$. Now, I am interested to study the motion of the particle in the $r-\theta$ plane. Spherical coordinates $(r,\theta,\phi)$ is used in the problem and the axial symmetry corresponds to the $\phi$ coordinate.

How to obtain the equations of motion from $\Phi_{eff}(r,\theta)$ that I can numerically integrate to obtain the trajectory of the particle?

Comment: You can use EL to obtain the Equations of motion

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Lagrange's equations.
Taking the Lagrangian $L$ as

$L = T - \Phi_{eff}$

Comment: Your answer is short enough that it can just be a comment.